# Building lightbox in React. Clicking first image shows, then the next images are empty objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

building this lightbox in React, the problem I am facing is that when I goto the next image in the array, it's empty and just showing "Object object" as the error. I am grabbing both the image and text from the array of objects. Anyone have any ideas? The showNext() function is where it's not working. Thanks

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Ant from '../../img/ant.jpeg';
import Bee from '../../img/bee.jpeg';
import Bedbug from '../../img/bedbug.jpeg';
import Wasp from '../../img/wasp.jpeg';
import Mouse from '../../img/mouse.jpeg'

// const images = [Bee, Ant, Bedbug, Wasp, Mouse];

const images_arr = [
  { image: Ant, text: "Ant" },
  { image: Bee, text: "Bee" },
  { image: Bedbug, text: "Bedbug" },
  { image: Mouse, text: "Mice" },
  { image: Wasp, text: "Wasp" },
]

function PestsGallery() {
  const [imageToShow, setImageToShow] = useState({});
  const [lightboxDisplay, setLightBoxDisplay] = useState(false);

  //looping through our images array to create img elements
  const imageCards = images_arr.map(({ image, text }) => (
    <>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <img key={image} alt={image} className="image-card" onClick={() => showImage(image)} src={image} />
    </>

  ));

  //function to show a specific image in the lightbox, amd make lightbox visible
  const showImage = (image) => {
    setImageToShow(image);
    setLightBoxDisplay(true)
  }

  //hide lightbox
  const hideLightBox = () => {
    setLightBoxDisplay(false)
  }

  //show next image in lightbox - this is where the error is happening, when i clicke the arrow the next image is empty.
  const showNext = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow);
    if (currentIndex >= images_arr.length - 1) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false)
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex + 1];
      setImageToShow(nextImage)
    }
  }

  const showPrev = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow);
    if (currentIndex <= 0) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false);
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex - 1];
      setImageToShow(nextImage);
    }
  };


  return (
    <>
      <h2> Bugs we treat</h2>
      <div>{imageCards}</div>
      {
        lightboxDisplay ?
          <div id="lightbox" onClick={hideLightBox}>
            <button onClick={showPrev}>⭠</button>
            <img alt="gallery" id="lightbox-img" src={imageToShow}></img>
            <button onClick={showNext}>⭢</button>
          </div>
          : ""
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default PestsGallery;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inconsistent types of imageToShow local state seems to be at fault (cannot test this without the actual repo). Typescript is great at catching this early.

`imageToShow` state has this type: `{ image: .jpeg, text: string }`.

In `imageCards` callback on the img you pass `{ image: .jpeg }` into showImage function, which then uses `setImageToShow` to set the image to show. Instead, you should be passing the correct state shape i.e. `{ image, text }`.

Also, in your jsx, you need to access the image component in img tag like so:
`<img alt="gallery" id="lightbox-img" src={imageToShow.image}></img>`

If you look at your `setImageToShow` calls in `showNext` and `showPrev`, the `nextImage` variable is the entire image object e.g. `{ image: Bee, text: "Bee" }`, since you access `images_arr` at a specific index (btw, keep you naming consistent to camelCase).

Code snippet aligned with above below for copy paste check:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Ant from '../../img/ant.jpeg'
import Bee from '../../img/bee.jpeg'
import Bedbug from '../../img/bedbug.jpeg'
import Wasp from '../../img/wasp.jpeg'
import Mouse from '../../img/mouse.jpeg'

// const images = [Bee, Ant, Bedbug, Wasp, Mouse];

const images_arr = [
  { image: Ant, text: 'Ant' },
  { image: Bee, text: 'Bee' },
  { image: Bedbug, text: 'Bedbug' },
  { image: Mouse, text: 'Mice' },
  { image: Wasp, text: 'Wasp' },
]

function PestsGallery() {
  const [imageToShow, setImageToShow] = useState({})
  const [lightboxDisplay, setLightBoxDisplay] = useState(false)

  //looping through our images array to create img elements
  const imageCards = images_arr.map(({ image, text }) => (
    <>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <img
        key={image}
        alt={image}
        className='image-card'
        onClick={() => showImage({ image, text })}
        src={image}
      />
    </>
  ))

  //function to show a specific image in the lightbox, amd make lightbox visible
  const showImage = (image) => {
    setImageToShow(image) // image is the object hence it will work
    setLightBoxDisplay(true)
  }

  //hide lightbox
  const hideLightBox = () => {
    setLightBoxDisplay(false)
  }

  //show next image in lightbox - this is where the error is happening, when i clicke the arrow the next image is empty.
  const showNext = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow)
    if (currentIndex >= images_arr.length - 1) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false)
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex + 1]
      setImageToShow(nextImage)
    }
  }

  const showPrev = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    let currentIndex = images_arr.indexOf(imageToShow)
    if (currentIndex <= 0) {
      setLightBoxDisplay(false)
    } else {
      let nextImage = images_arr[currentIndex - 1]
      setImageToShow(nextImage)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2> Bugs we treat</h2>
      <div>{imageCards}</div>
      {lightboxDisplay ? (
        <div id='lightbox' onClick={hideLightBox}>
          <button onClick={showPrev}>⭠</button>
          <img alt='gallery' id='lightbox-img' src={imageToShow.image}></img>
          <button onClick={showNext}>⭢</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default PestsGallery
```